# Measuring dynamic memory usage using C++ sanitizers

Tags: c++, gcc, memory, clang

I am looking for a simple way to measure the total memory used by a C++ application. I am aware of valgrind but recently I came across C++'s memory sanitizer. Is it possible to measure the max heap/stack memory used by a C++ executable binary using any sanitizer ?

Comment: that's not what sanitizer are made for so i don't think you can but you can do it other ways

Comment: What other way apart from Valgrind ?

Comment: These are not C++ sanitizers, but GCC or Clang sanitizers. And the "total memory used" does not makes much sense (a given process can get memory with `mmap` and release memory with `munmap` on Linux, so the used memory is varying with time)

Answer (score 1):

use `time -v` which can give you a bunch of useful information about an application as:

```
    System time (seconds): 0.00
    Percent of CPU this job got: 0%
    Elapsed (wall clock) time (h:mm:ss or m:ss): 0:05.00
    Average shared text size (kbytes): 0
    Average unshared data size (kbytes): 0
    Average stack size (kbytes): 0
    Average total size (kbytes): 0
    Maximum resident set size (kbytes): 2144
    Average resident set size (kbytes): 0
    Major (requiring I/O) page faults: 0
    Minor (reclaiming a frame) page faults: 179
    Voluntary context switches: 2
    Involuntary context switches: 1
    Swaps: 0
    File system inputs: 0
    File system outputs: 0
    Socket messages sent: 0
    Socket messages received: 0
    Signals delivered: 0
    Page size (bytes): 4096
    Exit status: 0
```